# How do I run multiple Apps on Express without routing?

Tags: node.js, express, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware, node-https

I have 2 apps I am looking to add to my profile website which itself is an express app.

I want to run these apps under a `/projects` route such that we can have `localhost/projects/app1` and `localhost/projects/app2`

I want all the sub routes for each app to be handled at their respective routes
 e.g the route `/projects/app1/signup` redirects after a successful  `POST` to the dashboard but now i need to make sure this does not redirect to `localhost/dashboard` but instead `localhost/projects/app1/dashboard`

**I am aware of routing and I ams also using it on App1 i.e**

```
var rank = require('./routes/ranks');
...
var taxiRanks = new rank();
...
app.get('/',taxiRanks.findNearbyRanks);
app.get('/whereami',taxiRanks.getCurrentLocation )
app.post('/location',taxiRanks.receiveLocation) 
app.post('/signup',taxiRanks.newUser)
```

***I WANT TO ACHIEVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS***

```
...
var main_app = express()
var app1 = require('./path/to/app1')
var app2 = require('./path/to/app2')
...
main_app.get('/projects/app1' , app1())
main_app.get('/projects/app2' , app2())
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Router API of Express :

```
// app1.js
const app1Routes = express.Router();

app1Routes
  .use('/user', userRoutes)
  .use('/activity', activityRoutes)

module.exports = app1Routes;


// app2.js
const app2Routes = express.Router();

app2Routes
  .use('/food', foodRoutes)
  .use('/candy', candyRoutes)

module.exports = app2Routes;

// app.js
const app1Routes = require('./app1.js');
const app2Routes = require('./app2.js');

app.use('/app1', app1Routes);
app.use('/app2', app2Routes);
```

And for example in userRoutes you could declare your routes like that :

```
const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({ id : 1, firstName : 'junk' }));

routes.post('/', (req, res) => res.status(201).send({ msg : 'User created' }));

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: and what would be contained in userRoutes, activityRoutes or foodRoutes ?